# Javascript countdown goes into negative when date has passed

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and playing around with making a countdown timer, I have managed to get to get it working to a degree, but can't get the timer to stop once it reaches 0, in the console it also throws an error, "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'timeinterval' before initialization"

Any help and advice would be great, thanks you in advance.

Below is the code.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return {
      total,
      days,
      hours,
      minutes,
      seconds
    };
  }

  function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    const clock = document.getElementById(id);
    const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
      const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

      daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

      if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
        console.log(timeinterval);
      }
    }

    updateClock();
    const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }

  const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date('2020-8-6')));
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Comment: Can you please tell, what is your expected output when the date is passed.

Comment: Currently when the timer finishes the clearInterval method works and stops the countdown, but the clock keeps going into negative numbers, I simply want it to stop at zero once the date has passed.

Comment: You can put your rendering code in else block.

`function updateClock() {
      const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
      if (t.total < 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
        console.log(timeinterval);
      }else{
         daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
         hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
         minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
         secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
       }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to understand the error message.

Move `const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);` above `function updateClock` and you'll be fine :)

[image: Edit dank-worker-j41rp]

Comment: Thanks for that, the only issue now is the countdown is showing negative numbers once the date has passed. -2 days etc would you be able to help me with that too?

Comment: I added a codesandbox link, if days have passed it will only display 0 0 0 0. Basically it will not update the `html` if `t.total` is negative.